# Creating SQL view with data based on relations from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new to SQL and I'm trying to create a SQL view in Microsoft SSMS. I've made some views that I am happy with, but with this one I ran in to some problems. I have made a simplified example trying to explain what it is that I'm trying to do.

Let's say I have three tables, one of them lists people, the second one lists colors and the third lists the relations between which people like which colors.

[image: Three tables]

What I'm trying to do now is create a view that presents one row per person that says whether or not the person likes the color red.

[image: View result]

```
SELECT 
    Person.Id, Person.Name, Color.Colorname, 
    CASE 
       WHEN ColorId = 4 THEN 'YES' 
       ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS 'Likes Red'
FROM 
    Person 
INNER JOIN 
    Color ON Person.Id = Color.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    PersonColorRelations ON Person.Id = PersonColorRelations.PersonId
```

Comment: Please show your query so someone can point out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Added what I've got, but it's not much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `exists` :

```
select *, (case when exists (select 1 
                             from PersonColorRelations pr 
                             where pr.PersonId = p.id and 
                                   pr.colorid = 4
                            )
                then 'Yes' else 'No'
           end) LikesRed
from Person p;
```

**EDIT :** For more you can do conditional aggregation :

```
select p.id, p.Name, 
       isnull(max(case when pr.colorid = 1 then 'Yes' end), 'No') as LikesBlack,
       isnull(max(case when pr.colorid = 2 then 'Yes' end), 'No') as LikesBlue,
       isnull(max(case when pr.colorid = 4 then 'Yes' end), 'No') as LikesRed,
       . . . 
from person p inner join
     PersonColorRelations pr
     on pr.PersonId = p.id
group by p.id, p.Name;
```

Comment: Another question:
If I wanted to add a column for each color that says 'Likes Black' 'Likes Blue' and so on, how would I go about that?

Comment: @Jeoell. . . You can do conditional aggregation. Check edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71213f/18

```
select p.id,p.name,
case when max(c.colorname) is not null 
  then 'Yes' else 'No'
  end as LikesRed
from
PERSON p
left join PERSONCOLORRELATIONS pc
on p.id=pc.NAMEID
left join COLOR c
on pc.colorid=c.id
and c.colorname='RED'
group by p.id,p.name;
```

If you want to derive another column (Like LikesBlue),then you just have to change color name in second last line.

Comment: Forgive me, what is the purpose of the max() and group by? To my mind it would work without these and just "case when c.colourname is not null"

Comment: Without group by we have multiple records for each `person`. We want only `not null` records and in case there is no match with `left join` that means `no`. Hence aggregate function. 
Try changing the fiddle which I created and remove the group by and max.
Having said that, I know this is not the best performance query out there. The accepted answers seems to be more precise.